# I can not install vlc on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: vlc

I tried to install vlc using the software centre and something pop up saying that

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

And from the details:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.0~pre2+git20141011+r57575+24+12~ubuntu14.10.1) but 2.2.0~pre2+git20141011+r57575+24+12~ubuntu14.10.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libavcodec-extra-56 (>= 6:11) but 6:11-1 is to be installed
     Depends: libavutil54 (>= 6:11~beta1) but 6:11-1 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.16) but 2.19-10ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libegl1-x11 but it is a virtual package
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.5.2-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-16ubuntu6 is to be installed
     Depends: libgles1 but it is a virtual package
     Depends: libgles2 but it is a virtual package
     Depends: libpulse0 (>= 1:1.0) but 1:4.0-0ubuntu22 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.6+git49-gbc62005+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.6+git49-gbc62005+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but 4.9.1-16ubuntu6 is to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

I tried using command and same thing happened. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: This is not duplicate. Its unmet dependency for mesa package

Answer (score 1):

So, I found my answer to this problem from
[here.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2250015)
TQ.

Answer (score 0):

Test this procedure:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In the open file, delete the content and paste this:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-proposed universe multiverse restricted main
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Continue run in a terminal:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install vlc
apt-get autoremove
apt-get -f install
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get clean
```

Comment: still cant install the vlc
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles1